# How do object references work internally in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to javascript. 
I have written the simple code:

```
var temp = {}
var arr = []

temp['a'] = ['a']
arr.push(temp)
console.log(arr);
```

As expected, it prints:

```
[ { a: [ 'a' ] } ]
```

But then, when I append the following line to the previous code:

```
temp['b'] = ['b']
arr.push(temp);
console.log(arr);
```

I would have expected it to print:

```
[ { a: [ 'a' ] }, { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] } ]
```

But it prints:

```
[ { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] }, { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] } ]
```

Entire code for unexpected result:
    var temp = {}
    var arr = []

```
temp['a'] = ['a']
arr.push(temp)
console.log(arr);

temp['b'] = ['b']
arr.push(temp);
console.log(arr);
```

**Why did the first element of array got updated?**

The following code gave me expected result:

```
var temp = {}
var arr = []

temp['a'] = ['a']
arr.push(temp)
console.log(arr);

temp = {};
temp['a'] = ['a']
temp['b'] = ['b']
arr.push(temp);
console.log(arr);
```

How does adding `temp = {}` helped here?

Comment: What do you mean by "extend it to this?" Can you give the full code that gives the unexpected result?

Comment: when you push an object to an array you are not adding a copy of that object but the object itself. if you modify that object somewhere else then the one you pushed is updated too, obviously it's the same object, both temp and the temp you pushed in arr reference the same object. when you redefine temp you are basically allocating new "memory" for it at a different address with a different reference. the one in arr still points to the old object so changing temp (now a different object) won't update the one in arr.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right about this. Temp is starting off as an object and then you're assigning it values as if it was an array...so why set it as an object to begin with? Unless my understanding is wrong.

Comment: `Why did the first element of array got updated?` Because quite simply, you updated the first element.  `temp` is still `temp`.  You have changed what is *within* the object, but you have not re-assigned it to a different object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects in Javascript are passed *by reference*.  That is, only one object is created and the symbol that represents that object can be used but it will refer to the same object always.

Lets take a deeper look:

If I'm understanding your example correct, this part

```
var temp = {}
var arr = []

temp['a'] = ['a']
arr.push(temp)
console.log(arr);
```

Creates a local variable `temp` to which you add `['a']` to.  You then push that into arr.

So at this point, `arr` references the object `temp` and looks like this:

```
[ { a: [ 'a' ] } ]
```

When you do this:

```
temp['b'] = ['b']
arr.push(temp);
console.log(arr);
```

The `temp` symbol which points to the original object containing `['a']` is updated, and so the `arr` will also get updated, so `arr` contains this at that point:

```
[ { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] }, { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] } ]
```

Finally,

You then do this instead:

```
temp = {};
temp['a'] = ['a']
temp['b'] = ['b']
arr.push(temp);
console.log(arr);
```

This creates a **separate** global variable `temp`, onto which you add both
`['a']` and `['b']`.  This is global because it **does not have** the `var` keyword in the declaration/initialization.  This then gets pushed into the `arr`.  However, since it's a global variable and not the original **local** variable, you see this instead:

```
 [ { a: [ 'a' ] }, { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In first case, `arr[0]` has `temp`'s reference, `arr[1]` also has `temp`'s reference. So, `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` have the *same* reference.

Hence updating the reference will update it everywhere where the reference is 
being referred.

In second case however, when you do `temp = {}` you're just reassigning `temp` to a *new* reference, before pushing it. So, there's no relationship between the `arr[0]`'s reference, and hence updating `temp` now, only affects it.

Answer (score 0):

The examples are not the same, it doesn't have to do with `temp = {}`.

In the first example you push `temp` twice, meaning `arr` has to references 2 `temp`.

After the first `push` you add another item to `temp` so within `arr`, if you had print it, you would have seen:

`[ { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] } ]`

So try this out on the console:

```
var temp = {}
var arr = []

temp['a'] = ['a']
arr.push(temp)
temp['b'] = ['b']
console.log(arr);
```

You'll see the result:

`[ { a: [ 'a' ], b: [ 'b' ] } ]`

Pushing another `temp` into `arr` is just going to result into two references into `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two data types in JavaScript - value types and reference types.

Value types are actually copied as they are sent between objects. This is because this is what you would expect for certain things like numbers and booleans.

Say I pass the number `1` to a function that stores it in an object `A`.

It would be surprising if I could then subsequently modify the value contained in `A` simply by modifying the value of the original number. Hence, pass by value. There are also optimizations that can be performed for value types.

Objects (i.e. **everything** other than number literals, boolean literals, null, undefined, and string literals*) are reference types in JavaScript and only their reference is passed around. This is largely for efficiency reasons. In your example, `temp` is an object. It is therefore passed by reference.

And so

```
temp['b'] = ['b']
```

Modifies the single existing instance of `temp`, thereby modifying the contents of `arr`, *before* you then also push `temp` into `arr` for a second time.

So you end up with an array containing two references to a single object `temp`, giving you the observed result.

* There is some complexity surrounding the string implementation that I am purposefully ignoring here.